# Why does GLPK produce the error `cannot execute glpsol.exe` while the default PuLP solver works perfectly?

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, pulp

While trying to solve a Binary Integer Programming Problem with PuLP and using GLPK as the solver, I get the following error. I have installed GLPK on Windows, set the path as well. The result of `pulp.pulpTestAll()` shows `Solver <class 'pulp.solvers.GLPK_CMD'> passed`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Cloud 5.py", line 464, in <module>
    resource(request, pmachine, l, q)
  File "C:\Python34\Cloud 5.py", line 238, in resource
    status = prob.solve(pulp.GLPK())
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pulp-1.6.1-py3.4.egg\pulp\pulp.py", line 1643, in solve
    status = solver.actualSolve(self, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pulp-1.6.1-py3.4.egg\pulp\solvers.py", line 346, in actualSolve
    raise PulpSolverError("PuLP: cannot execute "+self.path)
pulp.solvers.PulpSolverError: PuLP: cannot execute glpsol.exe
```

However, when I use the default PuLP solver, it runs perfectly fine. I am using `status = prob.solve(pulp.GLPK())` to call the solver. The full Python code is very long as such I have not posted it here. The output obtained from `prob.writeLP('problem.txt')` for PuLP is as follows:

```
\* Resource *\
Maximize
OBJ: 2 _y11 + 2 _y12 + 10 _y21 + 10 _y22
Subject To
_dummy: __dummy = 0
_C1: __dummy = 0
_C10: 100 _x121 + 200 _x221 <= 1024
_C11: _y11 + _y12 <= 1
_C12: _y21 + _y22 <= 1
_C13: _x111 - _y11 <= 0
_C14: _x112 - _y11 <= 0
_C15: _x121 - _y12 <= 0
_C16: _x211 - _y21 <= 0
_C17: _x212 - _y21 <= 0
_C18: _x221 - _y22 <= 0
_C19: _x111 + _x121 = 0
_dummy: __dummy = 0
_C2: __dummy = 0
_C20: _x211 + _x221 = 0
_C21: _x111 + _x121 = 0
_C22: _x211 + _x221 = 0
_C23: _x111 = 0
_C24: _x121 = 0
_C25: _x211 = 0
_C26: _x221 = 0
_C27: _x111 + _x112 + _x121 = 1
_C28: _x211 + _x212 + _x221 = 1
_dummy: __dummy = 0
_C3: __dummy = 0
_dummy: __dummy = 0
_C4: __dummy = 0
_C5: _x111 + 2 _x211 <= 4
_C6: _x112 + 2 _x212 <= 8
_C7: _x121 + 2 _x221 <= 4
_C8: 100 _x111 + 200 _x211 <= 1024
_C9: 100 _x112 + 200 _x212 <= 2000
Bounds
__dummy = 0
Binaries
_x111
_x112
_x121
_x211
_x212
_x221
_y11
_y12
_y21
_y22
End
```

Why does GLPK produce the error? Using the default solver, the output obtained is :

```
Optimal
Objective value: 12.0

The values of the variables : 

__dummy = None
_x111 = 0.0
_x112 = 1.0
_x121 = 0.0
_x211 = 0.0
_x212 = 1.0
_x221 = 0.0
_y11 = 1.0
_y12 = 0.0
_y21 = 1.0
_y22 = 0.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this is not an answer. I was planning to add this as a comment. But I cannot write a comment since I don't have 50 reputation now. So I'll just put it as an answer here.
I feel the problem is not in your program. Your program should be fine. But could be some issue in environment variables or permissions. If `pulp.pulpTestAll()`worked well for you, then it is supposed to have at least no such error `cannot execute glpsol.exe`. But you may unintentionally changed some setting which may cause this issue.

So here is something which can be helpful. Check out this block of code in [PuLP](https://github.com/coin-or/pulp/blob/695cffca07b184bf24782a07b8ef5d57fcdaf3ef/src/pulp/solvers.py#L320-L332) which is the reason why your program failed.

```
def executable(command):
    if os.path.isabs(command):
        if os.path.exists(command) and os.access(command, os.X_OK):
            return command
    for path in os.environ.get("PATH", []).split(os.pathsep):
        new_path = os.path.join(path, command)
        if os.path.exists(new_path) and os.access(new_path, os.X_OK):
            return os.path.join(path, command)
    return False
    executable = staticmethod(executable)
```

Different kinds of reasons like if such command exist in file path, if you have the access permission, if it is in environ path, etc. You may want to manually check each of them then you'll know for sure why your program failed.